# Entity Framework Core - Identity - Multiple Project

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework

I Have to projects

ASP.NET Core Web Application (.Net Core)

**ExternalEntityFramework**

and a Class Library (.NET Core)

**ExternalEntityFramework.Data**

[image]

This was created following [this link](http://www.jerriepelser.com/blog/moving-entity-framework-7-models-to-external-project/) but on .NETCore. I'm very confused now, since I cannot create the migration on the **ExternalEntityFramework.Data** since there is no Startup class, and I do not know how to in a Class Library project.

Can someone give me a little guidance on creating seperate project for Entity Framework Core data access?

Comment: I answered this quastion in [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48708562/asp-net-core-identity-for-multiple-project-with-identityserver4/59533767#59533767)

Comment: I answerd to this quastion(.net core projects) in [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48708562/asp-net-core-identity-for-multiple-project-with-identityserver4/59533767#59533767)

Answer (score 0):

You should have the following class in **ExternalEntityFramework.Data**.

```
public static class IServiceCollectionExtension
{
    public static IServiceCollection AddProjectServices(this IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddDbContext<SomeContext>(options => options.UseSqlite(connectionString, b => b.MigrationsAssembly("ExternalEntityFramework")));

        return services;
    }
}
```

With this class you add servicies inside your library project. Then you should call this method from the **startup.cs** on your main project, previously addition of a reference to **ExternalEntityFramework.Data**.

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddMvc();
    services.AddProjectServices();
}
```

You could pass **connectionString** and **ExternalEntityFramework** string as parameters.

```
public static IServiceCollection AddProjectServices(this IServiceCollection services, string connectionString, string mainProject)
```

I'm trying this myself, so maybe this is not the optimal way of doing this. But It works.