# ASP.NET Core Identity for multiple project with IdentityServer4

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, asp.net-identity, identityserver4

I have one solution with two MVC projects, which use the IdentityServer4. In one project I installed the IdentityServer4 and have full access to the database. The other project is an MVC client.

When I set the `[Authorize]` attribute on both project all works fine, but this role attribute `[Authorize(Roles = "user")]` works only in project one that has the IdentityServer4, the MVC client says:

```
Unable to resolve service for type   'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.UserManager`1[Entities.Application.ApplicationUser]' while attempting to activate 'IdMWeb.Controllers.AccountController' (this is the project one with the IdentityServer4 installed).
```

My questions are, why project one does not complain when I do not set the role attribute in project 2.
Also, how can project 2 get the role from the database?

Comment: How is Project 2 configured? That error is happening because you’re trying to use the ASP.net Identity UserManager without having it registered and configured. It’s nothing to do with the authorise attribute as far as I can tell. If you want Project 2 to have access to your user management db then you could register asp.net Identity and use the UserManager class like normal.

Comment: Show the configuration of projects and how they are protected by ID4 server. Also show how you have configured the resources in ID4 for these MVC projects.

Answer (score 0):

please see bottom link for asp .net core apps:

[Share authentication cookies path](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/cookie-sharing?view=aspnetcore-3.1)

simple answer:

please add bottom code in startup.cs ConfigureServices method of two or more ASP.NET Core projects :(be cureful the path "C:\sampleDirectoryInServer" exists in your server)

```
        services.AddDataProtection()
.PersistKeysToFileSystem(new DirectoryInfo(@"C:\sampleDirectoryInServer"))
.SetApplicationName("SharedCookieApp");

        services.ConfigureApplicationCookie(options => {
            options.Cookie.Name = ".AspNet.SharedCookie";
        });
```

it's work for me(2 asp.net core app with same database and different ports)

Answer (score -1):

Based on the error message your posted, It may be that you did not define a client on the server side for this particular client. A IdentityServer instance will only accept requests from clients that it already knows about.  You have to define the acceptable clients for it when you configure the middleware.